# How do I access the extras from an intent in RemoteViewsService?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I add extras to an intent like so:

```
Intent adapterIntent = new Intent(context, MyRemoteViewService.class);
adapterIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, currentWidgetID);
adapterIntent.setData(Uri.parse(adapterIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
views.setRemoteAdapter(R.someLV, adapterIntent);
```

In MyRemoteViewService.java, I tried to get the widget id like so:

```
@Override public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    String currWidgetID = intent.getData().getPath();
```

I used getData() instead of getExtras() because that always returned null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your intention is to set the "widget_id" in widgetProvider and getting in RemoteViewsService class once try this

```
Intent.putExtra(name, value) //set the data
intent.getIntExtra(name, defaultValue)//get data
```